# How to extract S.M.A.R.T. data from a storage on OsX? (C++)

Tags: c++, macos, iokit

The need is to access S.M.A.R.T. data ([Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)) for a storage diagnostic tool.

From Wikipedia:

> S.M.A.R.T. (Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology; often
>   written as SMART) is a monitoring system included in computer hard
>   disk drives (HDDs), solid-state drives (SSDs),[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) and eMMC drives. Its
>   primary function is to detect and report various indicators of drive
>   reliability with the intent of anticipating imminent hardware
>   failures.
>
> When S.M.A.R.T. data indicates a possible imminent drive failure,
>   software running on the host system may notify the user so
>   preventative action can be taken to prevent data loss, and the failing
>   drive can be replaced and data integrity maintained.

However, I could not find any relevant information about how to retrieve those values from a disk programmatically.

Note: Even if the question is tagged `IOKit`, it would run in user-mode (not a driver), but could require root privileges if needed.

Following is a sample code to list disk connected to the PC (**Not production-ready**):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
#include <IOKit/storage/IOMedia.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CFString.h>

using namespace std;

static void printPairs (const void* key, const void* value, void* context) {
  CFShow(key);
  CFShow(value);
}

int main() 
{
    // create matching dictionary
    CFMutableDictionaryRef classesToMatch;
    classesToMatch = IOServiceMatching(kIOMediaClass);
    if (!classesToMatch) cout << "Error: IOServiceMathing failed" << endl;

    // get iterator of matching services
    io_iterator_t mediaIterator;
    kern_return_t kernResult;
    kernResult = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault,classesToMatch,&mediaIterator);
    if (KERN_SUCCESS != kernResult) cout << "Error: IOServiceGetMatchingService failed" << endl;


    // Iterate medias
    io_object_t nextMedia;
    while ( (nextMedia = IOIteratorNext(mediaIterator)) ) 
    {
        CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = nullptr;
        kernResult = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(
            nextMedia,&dict, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
        if (KERN_SUCCESS != kernResult) cout << "Error: IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties failed" << endl;


        CFNumberRef objWhole = static_cast<CFNumberRef>(CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, CFSTR("Whole")));
        CFNumberRef objRaid = static_cast<CFNumberRef>(CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, CFSTR("RAID")));

        int64_t whole = 0;
        CFNumberGetValue(objWhole, kCFNumberSInt64Type, &whole);

        // skip partitions
        if (objWhole && whole)
        {
            io_name_t name;
            IORegistryEntryGetName(nextMedia, name);
            cout << "=============" << name << "============" << endl;
            CFDictionaryApplyFunction(dict, printPairs, nullptr);

            // PRINT SMART HERE

            cout << endl;
        }

        // clean-up
        CFRelease(dict);    
        IOObjectRelease(nextMedia);
    }
    IOObjectRelease(mediaIterator);
}
```

Comment: I believe **smartmontools** supports reading S.M.A.R.T. data from certain types of drives on macOS, you may have some success by consulting its source code. My guess would be you need to issue raw SCSI or ATA commands via an `ioctl()` on the device node.